# WPF Passing CommandParameter to the action Method RelayCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command

I am having trouble passing a parameter to the action method via XAML.

Here is my XAML

```
    <Button 
        Name="btnOK"
        Content="OK" 
        HorizontalAlignment="left" 
        Margin="961,253,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"  
        Width="67" 
        Command="{Binding CmdCloseWindow, Mode=OneWay}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ItemWindow}"
```

Here is my C# RelayCommand Code

```
        CmdGetProductItem = new RelayCommand<object>(p => GetProductItem(), p => CanExecute());
        CmdUnCommpressedFiles = new RelayCommand<object>(p => GetUnCommpressFiles(), p => CanExecute());
        CmdDeCommpressedFiles = new RelayCommand<object>(p => DeCommpressingFiles(), p => CanExecute());
        //CmdSaveProductItemChanges = new RelayCommand(t => SaveChanges(), t=> CanExecute());

        //Error is here
        CmdCloseWindow = new RelayCommand<Window>(p => CloseWindow( *** Asking to put parameter in here **** ), p => CanExecute());
```

But I am getting the parameter from XAML, so I cant put anything in the signature above, other posts state to leave it empty, but the complier complains.

Here is the method the RelayCommand calls.

```
    private void CloseWindow(Window window)
    {
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any help I would be grateful.

Comment: p is ItemWindow so why cant that be added to signature p => CloseWindow(p)?

Comment: I didn't know that about Lambda..thanks for the knowledge! However, it is complaining of an overload error now, so I guess p isnt of type window?

Comment: depends on your error. put a breakpoint in to have a look and let us know if still isn't working

Comment: It is still pre-runtime, the message is "the best overload match <the method> has some invalid arguments...

However, when I hover over the p, it states it is an object type, not a window type, is this correct?

Comment: Its difficult to say. You could try changing the command to RelayCommand<object> to get it to compile then inspect the parameter p

Comment: Thanks Delly, got there in the end! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for @dellywheel for pointing me in the right direction

basically, the lambda for the relaycommand - so in my case (p) is of type object, therefore, cast it to a Window object (The type of parameter you pass in), and it will work

```
  CmdCloseWindow = new RelayCommand<Window>(p => CloseWindow((Window) p), p => CanExecute());
```

Cheers